# Displaying Searchable ManyToMany field in Django form

Tags: django, django-forms

So in the admin UI for my many to many fields in my Dishes table (ingredients, boxes) the form element when I use the code below is a searchable box with the entire queryset for the related model for the field and that lets me move selections to a sister box for selected objects on the right. I do this with the following code in admin.py

```
class Dishes(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    filter_horizontal = ('ingredients', 'boxes',)
```

I am trying to replicate the same behavior in my frontend form that the users see, this is the code in my forms.py

```
class RecipesForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = models.Dishes
```

But all I get is a single plain multi-select box. How do I replicate what I did in the admin where I have one searchable box on the left and one on the right with objects I selected from the left?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply set the admin widgets for both fields:

```
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import FilteredSelectMultiple

class RecipesForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Dishes
        widgets = {
            'ingredients': FilteredSelectMultiple('Ingredients', False),
            'boxes': FilteredSelectMultiple('Boxes', False)
        }
```

Also you need to add admin static files (css, js) for the widget to work appropriately, please refer to this link for details:

http://jayapal-d.blogspot.com/2009/08/reuse-django-admin-filteredselectmultip.html

Comment: I get the following error point to the line in the code above starting with 'ingredients',                                    Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value: 
__init__() takes at least 3 arguments (1 given)